# JmsSerializer Encoding

Tags: php, symfony, encoding, utf-8, jmsserializerbundle

jmsSerializer encode perisan(or arabic) characters.

```
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    dump('test');
    dump($serializer->serialize('test', 'json'));
    dump('تست');
    dump($serializer->serialize('تست', 'json')); // <<---
    die();
```

[image]

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This the default json option. To disable it use [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) options.

Example global config:

```
jms_serializer:
    visitors:
        json:
            options: [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE]
```

Source: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/289#issuecomment-16569632